# SVG Images Disappearing After Expo App is Published

Tags: react-native, svg, expo

I am using 'react-native-remote-svg' to display SVG images in my react native expo app. Everything displays nicely on simulators/devices until I publish the app in Expo, at this point all SVG images disappear.

Example code:

```
import Image from 'react-native-remote-svg';
<Image
   style={styling.imageStyle}
   source={require('../res/images/sampleImage.svg')} />
```

Comment: Discovered that Expo doesn't support SVGs. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons

Answer (score 2):

You have to preload them, so they will be available in production build.

```
_loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
  return Promise.all([
    Asset.loadAsync([
      require('./assets/svg/some.svg')
    ]),
    Font.loadAsync({
      // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
      ...Ionicons.font,
      // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
      // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
      'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    }),
  ]);
};
```

In your App.js file of expo project.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!